# How do I write to data in the TableView from a custom UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` that populates “Characteristic” data from `HomeKit`.  The `UITableView` uses a custom `UITableViewCell`.  The cell has a label and a switch.  The cell `@IBOutlet` and `@IBAction` work properly allowing me to view the label and toggle/animate the switch in all cells.  However, I need the switch to write to the Data Source in the `UITableView` and I do not know how to reference/access the data from the `UITableView` in the custom cell.  I have determined how to get the `indexPath` of the selected cell.

I know there is a simple answer here ….. please help this iOS/XCode/Swift beginner.

```
import UIKit
import HomeKit

class CellServicesCharacteristics: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var switch1: UISwitch!

@IBAction func switch1Act(sender: UISwitch) {

    var cell = sender.superview?.superview as! CellServicesCharacteristics
    var tableView = cell.superview?.superview as! UITableView
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForCell(cell) as NSIndexPath!

    // How do I reference the Data Source from the TableView
    // so I can write to the Data Source?

    if switch1.on {
        label2.text = "On"
        // write to data source in tableview
    } else {
        label2.text = "Off"
        // write to data source in tableview
    }

}

override func awakeFromNib() {
super.awakeFromNib()

//Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

// Configure the view for the selected state
}

}
```

Comment: _write to the Data Source_ - what do you mean by this?

Comment: You should go through [Table View Programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH1-SW1)

Comment: I need to write to the HomeKit data source (essentially on/off from the switch) referenced by indexPath section/row in the TableView.  I do not understand how to define or reference the data source in the custom xib cell.  I know how to do it if I use the standard UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

Go in to the didSelectRowAtIndexPath over there you will get that

```
  func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!){
        println("Here is your selected indexPath \(indexPath.row)")
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: The didSelectRowAtIndexPath function runs when the row is selected, not when the Switch is selected.  Selecting the Switch, causes the "@IBAction func switch1Act" to execute in my custom UITableViewCell code.  When the Switch is selected, label2.txt toggles between "on" and "off" correctly.  I also need this function to toggle the data in the data source accordingly but do not understand how to access the data source from within this function.  I do have the correct indexPath.  I am sure it is very simple, but my inexperience with this environment has left me without an answer ....

Comment: Add tag to each switch button same as the indexPath.row with help this you will get the which cell is selected

Answer (score 0):

There are many approach to do that.
**Your Task**: To perform operation on HMCharacteristic object when switch is toggle.

**1st approach**
**I** - Create property of HMCharacteristic type in your custom cell.
**II** - Assign HMCharacteristic object in Tableview's cellForRowAtIndexPath.
**III** - In your custom cell class you are able to access object of HMCharacteritic class.
**IV** - On switch1Act() method call you can perform action to writeValue() method of HMCharacteristic

**2nd approach**
**I**  - You can define delegate in Customcell class and implement the delegate in UITableview's class.
**II** - Call this delegate in switch1Act () method call and pass appropiate index.
**III** - In your Tableview's implementation class, the delegate method will call. You can get HMCharacteristic from your char array to perform any operation on the Characteristic.

**3rd approach**
**I** - You can implement switch1Act() method in Tableview's class itself by setting target for your customcell's switch object.
**II** - You will receive method call in Tableview's class so no need to pass HMCharacteristic as property